# Hibernate & spring Could not synchronize database state with session

Tags: hibernate

I am getting the following exception

```
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1, SQLState: 23000
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-00001: unique constraint (DBNAME.ConstraintName) violated

org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
```

the error is pointed out in session.flush()

kindly help me

I am using spring webflow with hibernate

Comment: How are you setting your entities primary keys?  What is the value of your @GeneratedValue annotation

Comment: no i am setting values in hibernate config xmls , no annotations

Comment: Ok, how are you specifying your keys, sequence, identifier?

Comment: now i have given the key as increment

Comment: Here is where I'm going with this, check your database to make sure there is not a trigger.  If you previously had auto ddl set hibernate may have created a trigger for you which is causing a conflict with your key generation.

Comment: is there more than one client which inserts? increment is not applicable when there is more than one process/agent inserting data

Answer (score 0):

Exception clearly states that you violated a unique constraint for the given column, which means you're inserting same values in 2 records which is restricted by your schema.

Each RDBMS has means to show your the constraints, at least by having a DB Dump. Or they might have some additional syntax, like in MySQL you would write `show create table TABLE_NAME`. I don't know exact syntax in Oracle.

Also, you need to give to your constraints meaningful names, I hope `DBNAME.ConstraintName` is what you changed for the sake of example and it's not your real constraint name. In hbm.xml files you can set `unique="true" unique-key="meaningfull_uk"` for simple properties so that you know what actual constraint failed (you'll have to re-run your hbm2ddl in order to recreate it with new name).

Also, `Session#flush` is where Hibernate starts, but you need to inspect your code that invokes this operation and check there what possible values of saved entities could cause this problem.